# Can't proxy request with nginx to node.js (socket.io)

Tags: node.js, nginx

Tutorials and other answers doesn't help. I know that thing is in nginx config, but where?

I have CentOS 6.5, nginx 1.4.4, node 0.10.24, socket.io.js 0.9.16 and

in my_server_nginx.conf, node section:

```
location ~ /node {

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";      
    proxy_set_header Host $host;    
    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

}
```

in app.js:

`var io = require('/usr/lib/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.io').listen(3000);`

in html:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/node/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

in browser console:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined`

Direct open `/node/socket.io/socket.io.js` returns

`Welcome to socket.io.`

Answer (score 0):

In this case, '/node/socket.io/socket.io.js' is your socket root directory. and the socket.io js file will be served from within there. try linking to '/node/socket.io/socket.io.js/socket.io.js'